# WPF Datagrid adding BorderBrush to row causes row to shift on IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to find a way to highlight my data grid rows when I hover over them. The closest thing I found was adding a border to the datagrid row. However, in doing so it causes the row I am hovering over to shift to the right, slightly. On top of that it shows a horizontal scrollbar to appears at the bottom.

this is what I'm doing to the datagrid

```
    <Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSlateGray" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />                     
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

My question is this: is there another way to highlight the datagrid row?

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the element resizing when a border is added to it. The easiest option is to add a permanent border and make it visible or transparent.

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSlateGray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I apologize.
I did not pay attention that I sent it not in English.